# $X_n \downarrow$ and $X_n \overset{\text{p}} \rightarrow 0$, than $X \overset{\text{a.s.}} \rightarrow 0$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

How to show $X_n \downarrow$ and $X_n \overset{\text{p}}\rightarrow 0$, than $X \overset{\text{a.s.}} \rightarrow 0$?

Usually, we use BC lemma or the equivalent definition to show $X \overset{\text{a.s.}} \rightarrow 0$?

That is $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} P(|X_n-0|>\varepsilon)<\infty$ or $ \lim_{m\rightarrow\infty} P(\bigcup_{m=n}^\infty|X_n-0|>\varepsilon)=0$

It seems that $X_n \overset{\text{p}} \rightarrow 0$ means $P(|X_n-0|>\varepsilon)\rightarrow 0$ as $\rightarrow \infty$

I do not know how to apply the condition $X_n \downarrow$?

Comment: By $X_n\downarrow$, do you mean that $X_n$ is decreasing?

Comment: Yes! $X_n\downarrow$ means decreasing $X_1\supseteq X_2\cdots\supseteq X_n$

Answer (score 2):

Notice that by positivity and monotonicity, there is a (necessarily non-negative) random variable $Y$ such $X_n\stackrel{\text{a.e.}}\to Y$. However, $X_n\stackrel{\text{P}}\to0$ means that for all subsequences $X_{n_k}$ there is a sub-subsequence $X_{n_{k_h}}$ such that $X_{n_{k_h}}\stackrel{\text{a.e.}}\to 0$. Therefore $Y=0$ because $X_{n_{k_h}}\stackrel{\text{a.e.}}\to Y$ as well.

Comment: I do not know why by positivity and monotonicity, there is a (necessarily non-negative) random variable Y such that $X_n\stackrel{\text{a.e.}}\to Y$.

Comment: Because actually $X_n$ converges pointwise as a sequence of functions. That's just a property of real numbers.